# How to manipulate items in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am given a list of tuples, and I am trying to remove the white spaces after the strings in each list.
It can result in either a list of lists, or a list of tuples as the original structure.

I am able to remove the whitespace within the for loop, but when printing the lst back, it returns the original list.
The integers in the original list can be changed to strings.

```
lst = [(4, 'tim                ', 'dba', 7), (5, 'joe              ', 'sysadmin', 8)]
lists = [list(x) for x in lst]
    for y in x:
        y = str(y)
        y = "".join(y.split())
print(lst)
want it to return [('4', 'tim', 'dba', '7'), ('5', 'joe', 'sysadmin', '8')]
```

Comment: You should always explain what the problem is. Ideally include actual and expected results.

Comment: You've stated an objective. What is your question. Please read [ask] and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with - removing whitespace or recreating the structure?

Answer (score 3):

this list comprehension will [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the strings of leading and trailing whitespace:

```
[tuple(s.strip() for s in t) for t in lst]
# [('4', 'tim', 'dba', '7'), ('5', 'joe', 'sysadmin', '8')]
```